# Change the certificates validity in hyperledger Fabric is possible...?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am new in blockchain development. I just start a sample hyperledger project. The default expired period of certificates is 10 years. Have any solutions or ways are available to increase the certificate validity. I actually need to change it to 20 years. Please give any way to do it.

Fabric:1.1.0

Composer:0.19.16

OS:Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: see the Fabric CA Users Guide -> https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html?highlight=expiry (if referring to using cryptogen) - you can alternatively use something like openssl and customise accordingly.

Comment: But how it practicly apply

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony please give an answer as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just suggest to use Openssl for generate the self signed certificate.

eg:

openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365

//change day as you want. Hope it helpful.

Reference: [How to create a self-signed certificate with OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl)

Comment: Just to clear it up for other readers: RSA is not supported by Hyperledger Fabric. See https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/msp.html#how-to-generate-msp-certificates-and-their-signing-keys